# How to get started with Linq to sql?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am developing a new web application which would be simple and i decided to use asp.net mvc and Linq to sql..

I thus far have no idea about Linq to Sql...

- How to get started with Linq to sql?
- What should i watch out for when using Linq to sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of great tutorials...

- [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)
- [Joe Stevens](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2009/07/01/linq-to-sql-tutorial/)
- [hookedonlinq](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoSQL5MinuteOverview.ashx)
- [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/learn/linq-videos/video-232.aspx)

Also check out [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).  It will help you understand how Linq 2 Sql works a bit better, especially if you are already comfortable with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Also you should check out the ASP.NET site which has a great series of video tutorials to get you started in no-time
http://www.asp.net/learn/linq-videos/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try entity framework (microsoft's new orm) linq to sql is a bit
crusty