# Insert into 3 tables that are inter-dependent

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables-

```
1. Country (CountryName, CID (PK- AutoIncrement))
2. State (SID(PK- AutoIncrement), StateName, CID (FK to Country)
3. City (CityName, CID, SID (FK to State)
```

Now I need to insert only the name into the three tables with CountryName, StateName and CityName.. The IDs need to get updated.

How'd I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please clarify this.. when I enter a statename in  State table, how do I know which country it belongs to.? same case with City?

Comment: If this whole thing of inserting into more than one table at once is entirely new to you, you might benefit more if you started with the simpler case of just two tables. It's usually easier to learn new things when you start with the simpler problems and then move on to the harder ones.

Comment: Thanks Andriy, I have worked with 2 tables before, now when I use here, its a different scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use stored procedure to that inside the stored procedure you can first insert into the country table  :

```
Insert into Country ( CountryName) VALUES (@CountryName)
DECLARE @cid as INTEGER = @@IDENTITY
```

then use  SELECT @@IDENTITY in the secound insert like this :

```
Insert into State( StateName, cid ) values (@StateName, @cid)
DECLARE @SID as INTEGER = @@IDENTITY
```

and use the same in the third insert statment :

```
Insert into City ( CityName, CID,SID ) values (@CityName,@CID,@SID )
```

that is all what you need

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't it keeps increasing identity for same country?
As in, if I enter India twice, the value increases.. I want India= 1, Canada=2, always..

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use linq to SQL

```
var country = new Dbml.Country();
country.Name = "countryname";

var state = new Dbml.State();
state.Country = country;
state.Name = "stateName"

var city = new Dbml.City();
city.State= state;
city.cityName = "cityName";

context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this. Could you elaborate it?

Comment: You may want to see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182577/how-to-get-started-with-linq-to-sql) for Linq to SQL